# Is homeomorphism preserved by homotopy equivalence?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and suppose that $f:X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism. Suppose further that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $\tilde{X}$ and $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $\tilde{Y}$. Is $\tilde{X}$ necessarily homeomorphic to $\tilde{Y}$ with some induced homeomorphism $\tilde{f}: \tilde{X} \to \tilde{Y}$? I feel like this should be true maybe by some type of function composition with the homotopy equivalent maps. It is definitely true that the the spaces $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ are homotopy equivalent simply since homotopy equivalence is an equivalence relation and homeomorphic implies homotopy equivalent. Thoughts? Counterexamples?

Comment: The counterexample posted by FShrike below is a much better one, but the classic nontrivial example of spaces that are homotopy equivalent but not homeomorphic are $3$-dimensional lens spaces. (The proof is nontrivial.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very false. Let $X=\Bbb R,Y=\Bbb R,\tilde{X}=\ast,\tilde{Y}=\Bbb R$, $f=\mathrm{Id}_{\Bbb R}$. There is no homeomorphism $\tilde{X}\cong\tilde{Y}$.

However it's always true that $\tilde{X}$ is homotopy equivalent to $\tilde{Y}$.

Comment: Oh man very simple counterexample. Thank you!!

Comment: @TheSenate No worries.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be rephrased as follows:

> Are homotopy equivalent spaces always homeomorphic?

If that would be true, then you would find a homeomorphism $\tilde f : \tilde X \to \tilde Y$ because there exist homeomorphisms $h_x : X \to \tilde X$ and $h_Y : Y \to \tilde Y$.

Conversely, if we would always have a homeomorphism $\tilde f : \tilde X \to \tilde Y$, we could apply this to the case $\tilde Y  =Y = X$, $f = id$ and any space $\tilde X$ homotopy equivalent to $X$ and would obtain a  homeomorphism $\tilde f : \tilde X \to X$.

But homotopy equivalent spaces are in general not homeomorphic. Take $X = *$ and $Y= [0,1]$,

Comment: Well when you phrase it like that, it's clearly not true. I see now that is what the question was. Thank you for the insight.